# Поведение меню при кликах

Tags: html, jquery, html5

Есть такая загвоздка:

Как сделать так, чтобы при открытом подменю, кликая по другому пункту главного меню сворачивалось предыдущее подменю и появлялось другое которое соответствует тому пункту, по которому кликнули.

Надеюсь доходчиво объяснил. Желательно вариант на jQuery, если возможно.

Вот разметка меню:

```html
<div class="navigate__menu">
  <nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
      <li class="toggle-menu"><a href="#" class="down">Learn French</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="lrfrench.html">Learning French</a></li>
          <li><a href="frskype.html">French on Skype</a></li>
          <li><a href="howstart.html">How to start?</a></li>
          <li><a href="ourlessons.html">Our French lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="ourtutor.html">Our Tutor</a></li>
      <li class="toggle-menu"><a href="frenchcl.html" class="down">French Classes</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="gencourse.html">General Course</a></li>
          <li><a href="examsprep.html">Exams Preparation</a></li>
          <li><a href="convfr.html">Conversational French</a></li>
          <li><a href="busfr.html">Business French</a></li>
          <li><a href="civfran.html">Civilisation française</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle-menu"><a href="#" class="down">Book a Class</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="prices.html">Prices & Payments</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms.html">Terms & Condition</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-menu a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // для начала запретим стандартное страбатывание ссылки
  $('.submenu').hide(); // прячем все подменю
  $(this).parent().find('.submenu').show(); // и показываем текущее
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigate__menu">
  <nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
      <li class="toggle-menu"><a href="#" class="down">Learn French</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="lrfrench.html">Learning French</a></li>
          <li><a href="frskype.html">French on Skype</a></li>
          <li><a href="howstart.html">How to start?</a></li>
          <li><a href="ourlessons.html">Our French lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="ourtutor.html">Our Tutor</a></li>
      <li class="toggle-menu"><a href="frenchcl.html" class="down">French Classes</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="gencourse.html">General Course</a></li>
          <li><a href="examsprep.html">Exams Preparation</a></li>
          <li><a href="convfr.html">Conversational French</a></li>
          <li><a href="busfr.html">Business French</a></li>
          <li><a href="civfran.html">Civilisation française</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle-menu"><a href="#" class="down">Book a Class</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="prices.html">Prices & Payments</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms.html">Terms & Condition</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```